# updating the state for react-dates

Tags: reactjs, recompose, react-dates

I'm trying to use airbnb react-dates as follows:

```
function NewEntryModal(props) {
  return <Formik
      initialValues={{}}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
      }}
      render={props => (
        <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
          <SingleDatePicker
            date={props.date} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null
            onDateChange={date => props.setDate({ date })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired
            focused={props.focused}
            onFocusChange={(focused) => props.setIsFocused(focused)}
            id="string" // PropTypes.string.isRequired,
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      )}
    />
}

export default compose(
  withState('isFocused', 'setIsFocused', false),
  withState('date', 'setDate', moment()),
)(NewEntryModal);
```

I'm using [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) `withState` to update the date and focused states. However, I'm getting an error saying that `setIsFocused` is a not a function.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From wr SingleDatePicker this component being called share that component code

Comment: is `SingleDatePicker` declared in your `NewEntryModal` component ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Yes it is, please see the edited questin

Comment: @Student ok now I see what the problem is, The variable `props` is declared twice in your code, please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have two variables with the same name `props`

I think this could solve your problem, I used destructuring parameter for the `render` function

```
function NewEntryModal(props) {
   return <Formik
        initialValues={{}}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {}}
        render={({handleSubmit}) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <SingleDatePicker
              date={props.date}
              onDateChange={props.setDate}
              focused={props.focused}
              onFocusChange={props.setIsFocused}
              id="string",
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>
     )}
   />
}
```

By the way, I also changed `onDateChange` and `onFocusChange` to

```
onDateChange={props.setDate}

onFocusChange={props.setIsFocused}
```

because creating additional arrow functions is useless here

Comment: Thanks! I didn't catch two props. For onDateChange and onFocusChange, if not passing the "focused" and "date" without arrow functions, how does it know that it needs to pass those parameters? Arrow functions are my weakness :(

Comment: you need to pass a function to the parameter `onFocusChange`. Actually `props.setIsFocused` is already a function that already take one parameter so no need to use an arrow function here